# A python function for removing sublist from nested list

Tags: python, list, lambda, filter

I want to remove all occurrences of a  list from list of lists.
By that I mean I want to filter out all the occurrences of a given list.
E.g.

```
list = [[1,2,3], [3,2,1] ,[4,2,5],[1,2,3]]
list.removeList([1,2,3])
list=[[3,2,1],[4,2,5]]
```

I was thinking of using a filter or .remove() but it is giving me error. And for the filter I don't know what approach I should start with

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension

```
l = [sublist for sublist in l if sublist != [1, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [[1,2,3], [3,2,1] ,[4,2,5],[1,2,3]]
list2= list1

for i in list1:
    if i==[1,2,3]:
        list2.remove(i)
```

With append

```
list1 = [[1,2,3], [3,2,1] ,[4,2,5],[1,2,3]]
list2= []

for i in list1:
    if i!=[1,2,3]:
        list2.append(i)
```

Comment: You shouldn't modify a list that you're iterating over.

Comment: @Barmar explain what you mean

Comment: `list2` is a reference to the same list as `list1`, so you're calling `remove()` on the same list that you're iterating over with `for i in list1:`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list